# Errors using windows library and raylib

Tags: c++, windows, game-engine, raylib

Well, I want to make a program which the user can use the Windows Explorer for select a file and get the path. I have this code:

```
//main
#include "filedialog.h"
#include "raylib.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <commdlg.h>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    char szFile[MAX_PATH] = "";

    if (FileDialog::OpenFile(szFile, "All Files\0*.*\0", "Select file")) {
        std::cout << "Path: " << szFile;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
//filedialog.h
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>
#include <commdlg.h>

class FileDialog {
public:
    static bool OpenFile(char* filePath, const char* filter = "All Files\0*.*\0", const char* title = "Open File");
    
};
```

```
//filedialog.cpp
#include "filedialog.h"

bool FileDialog::OpenFile(char* filePath, const char* filter, const char* title) {
    OPENFILENAMEA ofn;
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = GetConsoleWindow();
    ofn.lpstrFile = filePath;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = filter;
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = title;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

    return GetOpenFileNameA(&ofn);
}
```

The IDE gives me a lot of errors (104). I have problems with raylib.h's functions. Without "raylib.h", everything is fine. What do I have to do???
Also, you can suggest me to use another library or give me a complete new code for solve this problem.